# How to Configure Rock Star Apps plugin in Eclipse for Concatenating and Compressing Javascripts

Tags: eclipse, minify, google-closure

I am using the rockstarapps plugin for concatenating and compressing/minifying .js files with Google Closure.
I chose the option to rebuild files when a dependency changes but now I would like to change the dependencies, output file, etc... How do I do that?

What does the 'Add to Auto-Building' option do?

thank you,

DM

Answer (score 1):

In the root of your project is an ant build file called .rockstarapps. 
This is Xml and human readable. 
The output file is specified near the top: `<file name="path/to/file.js">`

Auto Building: I assume this adds the file to the build section of .rockstarapps

Comment: Also, if you have an archive for this plugin, please post it online.

Answer (score 0):

The autobuilding option will only be activated if the files change, to add a new dependency, go to the .rockstarapps file and add up the line necessary, after saving just change some line into any of the dependencies and the file should be compiled with your new dependencies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<rockstarapps>
<file name="WebContent/js/extlib.core.all.js">
        <min>false</min>
        <comp>false</comp>
        <closureCompiler>false</closureCompiler>
        <gZip>false</gZip>
        <resolveImports>false</resolveImports>
        <urlRewriting>false</urlRewriting>
        <autoBuild>true</autoBuild>
        <lineLength>-1</lineLength>
        <autoTimestamps>false</autoTimestamps>
        <removeLogs>false</removeLogs>
        <oldFileNames>false</oldFileNames>
        <dependencies>
            <file>WebContent/ExtLib/core/modernizr.tdm.js</file>
            <file>WebContent/ExtLib/core/jquery-1.8.3.js</file>
            <file>WebContent/ExtLib/core/custom-tdm-jqm.js</file>
            <file>WebContent/ExtLib/core/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js</file>                       
            <file>WebContent/ExtLib/template/knockout-2.2.1.js</file>
        </dependencies>
        <properties/>
    </file>
</rockstarapps>
```